# How to capture emission light on a transparent plane similar to shadow catcher

Tags: rendering

**Problem**

I often use Blender to mockup products onto photos. I use Fspy to get the photo camera view, import into Blender, and export the scene as a transparent PNG. I then combine the render with the original photograph. I often use a shadow catcher to get realistic shadows when placing the render on the photographic.

I thought about placing the photo in the Blender and modeling the area, but that way might add too much time.

In my below example, I have several LED panels next to each other with an emission image for each LED panel. I could put a light shining outwards, but I am not sure how to capture that onto the plane to light on the photograph.

**Question**

If my render includes an emission, how can I get the emission data onto a transparent plane so it illuminates when placed on the photograph.

[image: LED Screens]